# HttpPost in a simple scenario passes null to a Controller method

Tags: c#

(VS2019 Preview 2 / Core 3 Preview 8)
When I set a break point in the controller, it is hit, but "text" comes in as null (I expect "foobar") ... I have tried a lot of things, you can see the encoding and application type commented out ... in either case, same thing. Am I missing some configuration?

Call site:

```cs
            string text = "foobar";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(text);//, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.PostAsync("http://localhost:49751/api/Data/PutDataAsync", content);
```

Controller:

```cs
        [HttpPost("PutDataAsync")]
        public void PutDataAsync(string text)
        {
            //a breakpoint here is hit, but "text" is null (should be "foobar")
        }
OR
        [HttpPost("PutDataAsync")]
        public async Task PutDataAsync(string text)
        {
            //same result, text is null
        }
```

Startup.cs:

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
string text = "foobar";
var fooJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(text); // trans to json string
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new StringContent(fooJSON , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
//...
```

Comment: Thank you, I just tried exact copy as you suggested, same result (I've tried and variations of that many times ... ultimately an object serialized to JSON is what I am intending ... just trying to break it down to bare essentials to isolate the issue